# Query get all latest records based on user_id

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called `photos` that has hundred of thousands of user uploaded photos.

Each user can obviously upload several photos.

The table schema is:

```
id, 
user_id, 
photo, 
date_created
```

I just want to get the latest record that each user_id has posted..

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM photos 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY date_created desc LIMIT 300
```

But that is obviously bringing back a lot of strange results.

This seems like an easy query, but I have done hours and hours of research on stack overflow and reading so many different articles on Google, and I can't for the life of me figure this simple query out.

Comment: Seems there is nothing wrong with your query if there is only one table. Describe what you mean by "strange results".

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the latest row for every user:

```
SELECT p.user_id, photo, date_created FROM photos p
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(date_created) max_date FROM photos GROUP BY user_id
) max_dates ON p.user_id = max_dates.user_id AND p.date_created = max_dates.max_date
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38e45/8)

Comment: This one did not work, it brough back random results, not the latest photos with distinct user id's

Comment: @MichaelMarcus Really? That seems odd as the query in the derived table determines the latest date a photo was posted for every user and that date is used to filter. Is anything different in your table compared to my sample?

Comment: Thank you so much for working with me here, I might be just having a hard time wording my problem.... But the table is the same... can I somehow give you my table with records?

Comment: also worth pointing out that is a slightly less efficient than my (fixed) answer using only a join and no subqueries.

Comment: @pala_ Yes, your version might be slightly more efficient depending on indexing etc.

Comment: @jpw ok this seems very very strange, but your example actually does work, but if there is a large record count in the table then the results are not accurate at all.... I created a table just like yours and ran your query like in your js fiddle and it worked.. but when I applied it to my table, it didnt work....

Comment: @pala_ same thing with you.. your example worked, but didn't work with a table with thousands of records... very stange

Comment: Can you put up a sample of your data? there has to be something funky about it

Comment: Yes, but how can I send you my sql file? Also, sql fiddle wont let me create a big table

Comment: not sure. how about you paste the results of our queries with the rows that are wrong, and the rows that you think would be the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

```
select p1.user_id, p1.photo, p1.date_created 
  from photos p1  left join photos p2 
    on p1.id < p2.id and p1.user_id = p2.user_id 
  where p2.id is null
```

try that

**EDIT**
forgot table name, my bad. added it in. also, here's a fiddle to see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a72f6/3

Comment: Thanks for checking it out, but that didnt even work at all, mysq says there is an error

Comment: @MichaelMarcus sorry - i forgot to include your table names. its fixed now, works and has an example.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I used `HAVING MAX(date_created)` to retrieve the records which are currently created/uploaded.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM photos 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MAX(date_created) 
ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 300
```

Comment: Ok this one didn't have any errors but it brought back very strange results, definitely not the latest record that each user_id posted

Comment: What do you mean strange results?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it did not bring back the latest photo records with unique user id's it just brought back random results from within the table, and not in any particular order

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to get rid of that GROUP BY and use a regular 'WHERE user_id = 'something', being the rest correct.

I tried a query like yours and the result was only one record by each 'user_id', lets say. GROUP BY usually uses a WHERE in the sentence...

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

I hope that helps :) If you get an error, please post it.